# trigger to change cursor_sharing for specific jobs

Tags: oracle11g

We are having a datastage application connecting to oracle database

so datastage job has a query as below

```
select * from 
table1 
where exist (select pid from table2,table3
             where date >sysdate -180)
```

so the subquery has million of records and as per OEM recommendation they want us to do `curosr_sharing`.so can you plaese let me know how to write a trigger which will only use cursor_sharing only for the specific user from datastage appliaction connecting to datbase to use the cursor_sharing = force or similar

and please let me know if we can go similar or force

Answer (score 0):

Would a before SQL statement not help here?

["IBM Knowledge Centre : Oracle Connector - Before / After Properties"](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.oracon.usage.doc/topics/r_before_after_properties.html)

I'd be guessing you'd need to put it into the BeforeSQL(node) section, if you're running multiple nodes that is

ALTER SESSION CURSOR_SHARING = FORCE;